# Search for data in firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So im trying to see if current user id is existing in database and want to return a bool value, the return data is of "Any" value and user constant is a String. i get the error on "if" "Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'contains'"

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef
    .child("Posts")
    .queryOrdered(byChild: "uid")
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in               
        print (snapshot.value)
        let returnData = snapshot.value
        if returnData.contains(user!) {
            print ("uid exists")
        }
    })
```

I get back this value from the database

```
"-LBe5petr8MUtVZd9qWw" = {
        uid = zQRxvM3cwzQMewUtVamk8JQrEFJ3;
    };
})
```

Comment: The right query is `databaseRef
    .child("Posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: "yourUserId")` and just check `if snapshot.exists()` in completion block.

Comment: That's indeed the correct approach @TheTiger. Can you write it up in an answer, so that we can upvote it and OP can accept it?

Comment: Thanks @Frank! I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right query is

```
databaseRef.child("Posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: "yourUserId")
```

and just check `if snapshot.exists()` in completion block.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a snapshot back, the uid must exist.  You could declare a `Boolean` which would update if data returned.  If you want the uid, you need to parse it like this:

`var userDoesExist: Bool = false`

```
    .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in               
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
            let userId = dict["uid"] as? String ?? ""
            print("Found uid: \(userId)")
            self.userDoesExist = true
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just search for Posts/User/uid and if the snapshot is empty the user doesn’t exist